# move values in stack to a vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector, stack

I am trying to move the elements that are in the stack into a vector. I have tried the following:

```
for(int i=0; i<vector1.size();i++)
{
    vector1[i]=stack1.pop();
}
```

But it keeps giving me error.

Comment: What error? We will need more info.

Comment: What are the types of vector1 and stack1?

Comment: Did you check to make sure that stack1.pop() returns an item? Also what is the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[*`std::stack::pop`*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/pop) doesn't return a value

You need to use [*`std::stack::top`*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/top), to get top element and then remove it from the stack like following :

```
   vector1[i]=stack1.top();
   stack1.pop();
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::stack<T>::pop()` [doesn't return a value (it's a void function)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack/pop/). You need to get the top, then pop, i.e.

```
for(int i=0; i<vector1.size();i++)
{
    vector1[i]=stack1.top();
    stack1.pop();
}
```

Comment: OPs original `for` loop may be confused.  Question is how to move elements in stack to a vector, but `for` loop uses vector `size()` as test condition.

Comment: Yeah. I'm hoping it's pre-allocated though, as writing to vector indices which don't yet exist is undefined (although then you should be using `.capacity()`. The whole code seems a bit wrong TBH.

Comment: @P0W and slugonamission solved it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

That's because the pop() function does not return a value.

You need to use top() which returns the element at the top of the stack and then pop() to eliminate that element...

```
for (int i = 0; i<vector1.size(); i++)
{
    vector1[i] = stack1.top();
    stack1.pop();
}
```